# Comparing Object Fields with Django's ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Is comparing columns in different tables using less-than/greater-than operators supported in Django's ORM?

For example, I'm trying to compare two object fields in a Django query, which would have the SQL equivalent of:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM mytable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN myothertable b ON b.id = a.other_id AND a.val < b.someval
```

Clearly, I can't use the normal filter() notation, since the RHS assumes the value is a literal, not an object/attribute name. e.g.

```
MyTable.objects.filter(val__lt=other__someval)
```

Comment: Did you read this yet? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model  It seems clear how it works.  What was confusing about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S.Lott's answer is the way to go. Here's an example of using F:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    val = IntegerField()
    model_b = ForeignKey('ModelB')

class ModelB(models.Model):
    val = IntegerField()


>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> ModelA.objects.filter(val__lt=F('model_b__val'))
>>> print qs.query
SELECT `test_modela`.`id`, `test_modela`.`val`, `test_modela`.`model_b_id` FROM `test_modela` INNER JOIN `test_modelb` ON (`test_modela`.`model_b_id` = `test_modelb`.`id`) WHERE `test_modela`.`val` <  `test_modelb`.`val`
>>>
```

Comment: It wasn't an answer.  It was a question.