# How to make a query that filters rows in which one column equals another one of the same table?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Say I have a model that looks like:

```
class StockRequest(models.Model):
    amount_requested = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    amount_approved = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

Is there any way to make a django query that would show me all requests where there is some relationship between amount_requested and amount_approved on a particular object/row?

In SQL it would be as simple as:

```
select * from stockrequest where amount_requested = amount_approved;
```

or

```
select * from stockrequest where amount_requested = amount_approved;
```

In Django, I'm not sure if it can be done, but I would imagine something like the below (NOTE: syntax completely made up and does not work).

```
StockRequest.objects.filter(amount_requested="__amount_approved")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing Object Fields with Django's ORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877856/comparing-object-fields-with-djangos-orm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Django queryset filter comparing two date fields in the same model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380448/how-to-create-a-django-queryset-filter-comparing-two-date-fields-in-the-same-mod)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import F
StockRequest.objects.filter(amount_requested=F("amount_approved"))
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You can [use the built in "F" object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) to do this.

The syntax would be:

```
from django.db.models import F
StockRequest.objects.filter(amount_requested=F("amount_approved"))
```

or

```
StockRequest.objects.filter(amount_requested__gt=F("amount_approved"))
```

Note: I found the answer immediately after I finished writing the question up. Since I hadn't seen this on Stack Overflow anywhere, I am leaving it up with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) on the `F()` function: