# How to create a Django queryset filter comparing two date fields in the same model

Tags: django, django-queryset

Trying to get a query where the Activity record is stale in my Solr Index.
I want to check to see if the `Activity.updated` date in the database is greater than the `Activity.added_toSolr_date` for the same record.

```
stale_activities_queryset = Activity.objects.filter(updated__gte = self.added_toSolr_date)
```

Model

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    # Last time entry / metric was updated in the Activity model database
    updated =  models.DateTimeField( verbose_name="CRUD date")
    # When it was added to Solr Index Date
    added_toSolr_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Added to Solr Index Date")
```

I referenced Django Query docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/
And unit tests for samples:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/modeltests/or_lookups/tests.py

Also searched here on Stackoverflow.  All the examples use an entered date instead of comparing two date fields in the same model.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

## [F objects.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)

```
from django.db.models import F
stale_activities = Activity.objects.filter(updated__gte=F('added_toSolr_date'))
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  How did you discover this?

Comment: @CarlosFerreira, through years of using django every day. I can't really say when.

Comment: nice solution! nearly posted the same question

Comment: How do we use F objects to compare just the date of a DateTimeField to a DateField?

Comment: @Sapphire you have to take the datetime field, make it a call the .date() method, then compare. I don't believe you have a direct F() object to use to do this, and must be manual.

Comment: This seems to fail if one of the dates is NULL.  Using Q to check for null or compare and still fails.  Even though it would not in MySQL, anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Here a good reference [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters)

Comment: @PaulKenjora Did you ever figure this out?  I am trying to use something like this: `test_qs.exclude(start_date__exact = F('end_date'))` and it is excluding all results where `end_date` is Null.  I also tried `start_date = F('end_date')` first; same result.

Comment: @jenniwren Sorry I ended up abandoning it as a query and just did my checks in code.  Maybe you could use a custom query?

Comment: @PaulKenjora would another option be to first query and filter out anything with null dates, then filter again for the date comparison?  Or do you need to include null dates in your results?

Comment: @Sapphire you can use `__date` lookup for DateTimeField, it will cast it to Date on SQL level. (yeah, answer after almost 6 years)

Comment: how about comparing two F?

Comment: Using `F` ended with this mistake
```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause.
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution of Yuji Tomita, unfortunately, didn't work.

Consider a model below:

```
class list(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField()
```

Queryset:

```
my_list = todolist.objects.order_by('created').filter(created__gte=F('modified'))
```

Template:

```
{% if my_list %}
{% for list in my_list %}
{{ list.text}}
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<p>there is no list</p>
{% endif %}
```

In the end I get an empty list, but I know, it is not correct. I have also used the following inside the template (without queryset filter):

```
{% if list.created|date:'d m y h:i:s' == list.modified|date:'d m y h:i:s' %}
```

It worked, but I would prefer to see a more elegant solution.

Comment: At a quick read it looks like you are doing two different things in your queryset filter and y our template code.  In the former you are using 'gte' and in the latter you are using '=='.  Is this why the two don't produce the same results?  I'm trying to figure out why using `mydate__exact = F('my_other_date')` in a query doesn't work when 'my_other_date' is None, myself.

Comment: I had another reason why it wouldn't work. Using `django-extensions` `TimeStampedModel`, the `created` and `updated` timestamps equal down to the milisecond. There is a minimal delay. My quick fix was to just compare it down to the second.