# How can I do to filter on the dates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am programming using django and I have this variable :

```
a = '2019-08-03'
```

And I have a database with two columns start and end like this :

```
start = 2019-08-01 00:00:00.000000
end = 2019-08-15 00:00:00.000000
```

Obviously start and end have many values. I would like to get the rows which a is between start and end. How can I do ?

I thought to something like this :

```
c = myObject.objects.filter(mycondition)
```

but I guess I have to do a conversion right and then something like between... Could you help me please ?

I precise I can modify a like this`a = 2019-08-03 00:00:00.000000`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Django queryset filter comparing two date fields in the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380448/how-to-create-a-django-queryset-filter-comparing-two-date-fields-in-the-same-mod). And [documentation on query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions). I suggest you read it carefully since it will answer almost all questions you might have on filtering

Answer (score 0):

You can filter these such that the conditon `start ≤ a ≤ end` holds:

```
Model.objects.filter(start__lte=a, end__gte=a)
```

If you want to boost fitering, it might help to add a `db_index` on both your `start` and `end` field.