# Django queryset filtering, comparing fields with fields

Tags: django

I would like to filter a queryset where the homecountry is the same as the residentcountry. I try to do something like this:

```
users = User.objects.filter(homecountry=residentcountry)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Django queryset filter comparing two date fields in the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380448/how-to-create-a-django-queryset-filter-comparing-two-date-fields-in-the-same-mod)

Answer (score 1):

Considering `homecountry` and `residentcountry` are two fields in your table. [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) can be used for this. Please check the documentation...

```
from django.db.models import F

users = User.objects.filter(homecountry=F('residentcountry'))
```