# Django filters two fields in different records with the same value

Tags: django, filter

In Django, I have a large amount of data（real data is about tens of thousands）. I want to find all records with the same amount of income and expenditure. What should I do?
Mysql:

| id | income | expenses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.00 | 50.00 |
| 2 | 0.00 | 43.00 |
| 3 | 50.00 | 0.00 |
| 4 | 50.00 | 0.00 |
| 5 | 29.00 | 0.00 |
| 6 | 23.00 | 0.00 |
| 7 | 0.00 | 23.00 |
| 8 | 0.00 | 5.00 |
| 9 | 0.00 | 12.00 |

I want to filter out data 13467. All expenses and income amounts have the same data (excluding the amount is 0.00)

| id | income | expenses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.00 | 50.00 |
| 3 | 50.00 | 0.00 |
| 4 | 50.00 | 0.00 |
| 6 | 23.00 | 0.00 |
| 7 | 0.00 | 23.00 |

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
from django.db.models import F

data = Model.objects.filter(income_field=F("expenses_field_name")).exclude(income_field=0)
```

same question with Datetime Field.  [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12380982/16250404)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.
My understanding is that your response is comparing the values of the "income" and "expenses" fields in a record, but what I need is to compare, for example, the "income" of id=1 with the "expenses" of other ids to find the same value.

Comment: can you share your expected results like `queryset` or any `aggregate result`?

Comment: ```
from itertools import chain

list_id = []
for i in Model.objects.filter(income__gt=0):
    ids = Model.objects.filter(expenses=i.income).values_list("id",flat=True)
    list_id.append(ids)

#flatten the list of lists
list_id = list(set(chain.from_iterable(list_id)))
```
# I want to implement this function, but my data volume is too large, and I don't want to use the for loop to implement it. I want to know if there is a simpler way.

Comment: i meant how data will look as per requirement. if income of id=2 and expense from id=4 are same suppose. then what should be the response format?

Comment: Response queryset, I need to display all the same data of expenditure and income on templates for users to further process these data.